# how to display values/lables on top of JFree 3D Bar graph

Tags: jfreechart

I am creating 3D Bar Graph. I want to display the values on top of each bar. but when i create 2D bar graph values are displayed outside. but incase of 3D bar graph values will be displayed inside the bar. How can we achieve this. Pls help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BarChart3DDemo4` is an example, as shown in the [JFreeChart Demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).